# Spring Roo with Spring MVC 4

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-roo

Currently am using Spring Roo 1.3 to build a prototype, and i notice that the xsd used in the Spring MVC is pointing to the MVC 3 version. Is Spring 4 supported from Spring Roo `web mvc` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it isn't supported, but you can customize generated views as needed.

Next release of Roo, the version 2.0, will generate apps based on Spring 4+.

Stay tunned!

Comment: is there any roadmap or target release date for it?